# How can i display array values, only if the number i greater than 50000? javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

In income-greather-than-500k.html you will find an array of tax forms assigned to the variable
called taxForms .
In its current state the entire array is logged to the console. You need to

**change the Javascript such that
only the real name of the superheroes that have an income greater than 500 000 are logged with
console.log .**

This is the taxform:

```
const taxForms = [
  {
    realName: "Bruce Wayne",
    income: 750000,
    wealth: 300000
  },
  {
    realName: "John Blake",
    income: 440000,
    wealth: 832000
  },
  {
    realName: "Selina Kyle",
    income: 640000,
    wealth: 432000
  }
];
```

Comment: This looks like homework or something. You also didn't post any of the JavaScript that does anything. What have you tried, what have you done?

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem. If you have a specific question, we'd be glad to help. But we won't do your homework for you.

Comment: Yeah, I an new to Javascript. This is "homework" that isn't in the corriculum, but i wanted to try it anyways, except I don't even know where to start. This is the first part, so if I get going with this one, maybe I can get through the rest.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use filter.

```
taxForms.filter(function(s) { return s.income > 500000 }).forEach(function (s) { console.log(s.realName) });
```

Comment: Thank you :) It's something like this I was looking for